# Abrindo e lendo arquivos gigantes em C

Tags: c, arquivo

Como posso abrir um arquivo pra leitura em linguagem C, acima de 100 MB?

Com este código colocado abaixo, consigo ler um arquivo com mais de 18.000 linhas, mas o que preciso mesmo é ler um arquivo com aproximadamente 5.000.000 ( 5 milhões de linhas ).

É possível isto em C?

```
char **xxxx;
    if ( ( arq = fopen("Meuarquivo.txt", "r+b" ) ) == NULL ){
        printf("Houve um erro na abertura do arquivo");
        getche();exit(1);
    }
xxxx = ( char** ) malloc ( 19000 *sizeof ( char* ) );
    while ( feof ( arq ) == 0 ){
        nomes [ c ] = ( char* ) malloc ( 19000 *sizeof ( char ) );
        fgets ( nomes [ c ], 19000, arq );
        ++c;
    }
```

Comment: 5.000.000 de linhas com 19.000 caracteres cada dá mais de 88Gb de RAM. 5.000.000 de linhas com 80 caracteres cada dá aproximadamente 400Mb de RAM.

Comment: Não amigo, posso ter colocado errado, por linhas deve ser em torno de 100 caracteres

Comment: Antes de mais nada, você tem certeza que precisa usar o arquivo todo na memória de uma vez só? Normalmente se for processar o arquivo para outra coisa, pode ir lendo e trabalhando nos dados sequencialmente, não tem motivo pra guardar na memória o que já foi processado.

Comment: Não consigo lê o arquivo por partes, já tentei limitando início e fim com laço for, más só funciona num arquivo todo lido

Comment: Coloca todo seu código que faz leitura. Veja [MVCE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Diga o que acontece quando tentar ler o arquivo grande. Dá erro? Qual? Testou para ver qual é o tamanho que começa dar erro?

Comment: Não que eu esteja recomendando mas você já tentou ler o arquivo todo de uma vez?

Comment: Claro que tentei, inúmeras vêzes..Vou lhe dizer uma coisa, eu criei um código por aqui, onde faço leitura de um arquivo por partes, escolhida no terminal, seno início e fim, apresento o total de linhas lido na escolha e em seguida faço uma pesquisa, e funciona perfeitamente, más só são 18.178 linhas, o que é isto perto e quase 5.000 000 de linhas? bem que eu gostaria de poder fazer o mesmo com este código más não funciona

Comment: Você não passa informações importantes para te ajudar, dizer que não funciona não dá subsídios para ninguém te ajudar. Faça o que eu te falei. Eu gostaria de responder mas não tenho nem por onde começar com tão pouca informação. Eu posso passar uma solução e você dizer que continua não funcionando. Mesmo que funcione comigo.

Comment: @SamuelLima qual o sistema operacional e compilador que você usando? O quanto você consegue alocar depende de muita coisa.

Answer (score -1):

```
char **xxxx;
if ((arq = fopen("Meuarquivo.txt", "r+b")) == NULL) {
    printf("Houve um erro na abertura do arquivo");
    getche();
    exit(1);
}
int c = 0;
xxxx = malloc(5000000 * sizeof *xxxx); // 5 milhoes de linhas
if (!xxxx) /* erro */;
while (1) {
    xxxx[c] = malloc(100);             // com no maximo 99 caracteres cada
    if (!xxx[c]) /* erro */;
    if (fgets(xxxx[c], 100, arq) == NULL) /* erro */;
    ++c;
    if (c = 5000000) /* erro */;
}

// usar xxxx

for (int k = 0; k < c; k++) free(xxxx[k]);
free(xxxx);
```

Comment: Vou testar e já te falo

Comment: Aqueles "números mágicos" (`5000000` e `100`) deviam ser uns `#define`s

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
invalid conversion from `void*' to `char*' main.cpp /main/src line 71 C/C++ Problem

Comment: Oops ... não estás a usar um compilador de C (nem, possivelmente, a linguagem C). Eu não te posso ajudar com C++ pois não conheço essa linguagem.

Comment: vou compilar no C, aguarde

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Suspicious semicolon LunaC.c /LunaC/src line 85 Code Analysis Problem
Suspicious semicolon LunaC.c /LunaC/src line 88 Code Analysis Problem
Suspicious semicolon LunaC.c /LunaC/src line 89 Code Analysis Problem
Suspicious semicolon LunaC.c /LunaC/src line 91 Code Analysis Problem
Até que compilou apesar dos warnings, más fechou o terminal do windows

Comment: Nos `if`s onde eu meti `/* erro */;` substitui por um tratamento de erro adequado.

Comment: O windows fecha o programa bem antes da leitura do arquivo, más valeu muito obrigado